# Retrofit POST with multiple query params

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I would like to do a POST Command.

This is my endpoint: http://180.150.134.136:18095/WSCoreAPI/send/receive/tester?method=LOGN&data=(urlencodeddata)

my question is how will i structure the endpoint in my retrofit

i did something like this:

```
@POST("WSCoreAPI/send/receive/tester")
Call<LoginResponse> tester(
        @QueryMap Map<String, String> data);
```

but it is not working

as well as this:

```
@POST("WSCoreAPI/send/receive/tester")
Call<LoginResponse> tester(
        @Query("method") String method,
        @Query("data") String data);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: the error comes from my api. I don't know how to log the actual url request sent to the api. So im guessing there seems to be a problem in structuring the endpoint of my retrofit

Comment: Can you put android logcat to understand it more clearly

Comment: You can log request and response using [okhttp logging interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor)

Comment: @fvthree you should implement callback interface with onSuccess and onFailure methods in retrofit. In onFailure case it will throw an exception saying that error about the rest call. Please try to log that error in android logs. monitor that logs in android monitor and add the image. This will help you to debug the issue. This will hep us to understand the issue with the call.

Comment: ^can you give me a proper example for using that library

Comment: @K Sathish it does not throw an error at the Failure section. The error seems to be making the request to the endpoint. I think data is not included in the url request

Answer (score 1):

Use @Field and @FormUrlEncoded for url encoded fields

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("WSCoreAPI/send/receive/tester")
Call<LoginResponse> tester(@Field("method") String method,
                           @Field("data") String data);
```

Comment: still no luck. I'm still getting the same error from my api

Comment: @fvthree did you try same with Postman or any other clients? Your sample says `&data=(urlencodeddata)` and you are using POST method but, the data you are passing is a part of a Query. When you use `@Field` or `@FieldMap` retrofit will add it in a post body, not the query. And your server should accept post body.

Comment: I tried using Postman. The server should not accept a post body. The "method" and "data" should be included in the url when making the request. I need the query

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("WSCoreAPI/send/receive/tester")
Call<LoginResponse> tester(@FieldMap Map<String, String> parameters);
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay so I got it working.

I used either two of the above solutions.

what i did was i removed the url encoding of the "data" query params and used this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("WSCoreAPI/send/receive/tester")
Call<LoginResponse> tester(@Field("method") String method,
                           @Field("data") String data);
```

removing the url encoding fix the problem because retrofit will automatically encode the fields annotated with @Field